# Alternative to union all in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, union-all

I want to write the below query without using union all. The only difference in both the queries are for `'Event'` and `'Time1'` columns:

Comment: `union all` is `union all` it is not wise trying to not using the tool specific for this and expect to get the same result.

Comment: also why is this even a problem. isn't `union all` serve his purpose?

Comment: I am getting the desired result from the above query, but I have similar 10 union all in the continuation of the above query and it looks very cumbersome

Comment: Your union logic is generating new records.  Union is the right tool for this job.

Comment: @T.Peter can you please help me in this?

Comment: quote Tim comment, `union all` will fetch every record no matter dupe or not, `union` will not include duplicate data.

Comment: but in this case since all your data got `Event` which will make every row in both table get union together. `union` will not help you.

Comment: any different way of writing the query without using union/union all?

Comment: NO, but I think the problem is you are using wrong tools all along. you are using same table in both select clause (with exactly same where condition) which I assume you don't need to use `union` at all. you should however use `case` to indicate `Event` and `Time1` .

Comment: @ravishraja why did you vandalize your own post? It makes no sense to anybody else now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
Select  L.id
,       L.StudentID
,       L.Name
,       L.Owner
,       O.Stage
,       O.probab
,       Multiplier.Event as Event
,       Multiplier.Time1
From    Lead L 
CROSS APPLY (
                VALUES  ('Lead', case when L.converted='true' and convert(varchar,L.ldate,23)<>convert(varchar,O.odate,23) then O.date else L.date end)
                ,       ('Contact Attempt', case when L.Attempted is null then O.Attempted else L.ContactAttempted end)
            ) AS Multiplier(Event, Time1)
left join Opp O
        ON O.LeadID=L.LeadID
left join Acc A 
        ON A.id=O.AccountId
left join zip Z 
        ON z.CODE = left(L.postalcode,5)
where (L.ldate is not null or o.NewAssigned is not null)
```

By the way, you should always define the length of `varchar`.

Comment: Thank You so much, this query worked. I have just added the cross apply conditions after all the joins